# Prove inequality $e-(1+1/t)^t < \frac{e}{2t+1}$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to prove that
$$e-(1+1/t)^t < \frac{e}{2t+1}$$

I got a lower bound
$$\frac{e}{2t+2} < e-(1+1/t)^t$$ using Hermite-Hadamard inequality.

Any hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the inequality $e-(1+\frac1t)^t < \frac{e}{2t+1}$ as
$(1+\frac1t)^t > \frac{e}{1+\frac1{2t}} $,
which is equivalent to
$$(1+x)^{\frac1x } (1+\frac x2 )> e\tag1$$
with $x =\frac 1t$ over the domain $x>-1,\> x\ne 0$. Observe
$$\frac1x \ln(1+x)
+\ln(1+\frac x2)-1= \int_0^x \frac{g(t)}{t^2}dt \tag2$$
where
$$g(t) = \frac{t(t^2+2t+2)}{(t+1)(t+2)} -\ln(1+t)$$
Note that $g(0)=0$ and
$$g’(t) = \left(\frac t{t+2} \right)^2 \left(\frac1{t+1} +t+4\right)> 0$$
for $t>-1$, which means $ \int_0^x \frac{g(t)}{t^2}dt >0$ and, according to (2)
$$\frac1x \ln(1+x)
+\ln(1+\frac x2)>1$$
Apply the inequality as the power of $e$ to obtain (1).